# Counting the number of rows with a certain weight in the row space of an $m \times n$ matrix in $F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a matrix with special form (close to the lower-triangular shape). An example:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
I want to count the result of all the linear combinations of the rows of this kind of matrix with the weight (in $F_2$, binary only) equal to the minimum row weight of the matrix itself (or any other lower weight). My matrix is actually quite large, e.g. 50 x 256 or a bit small or even larger than this. The number of columns is always a power of two.

Is there any way in linear algebra to enumerate such a thing?

It would be very helpful if you can give me some clue or a reference to get some help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: In general, you can look up weight enumeration for linear codes. in your case specifically, you can reduce that matrix to get a very nice basis for your row space. After doing that, it should be **VERY** easy to figure out the number of vectors of each weight for a matrix with this form.

Comment: (For example the matrix you show gives a row space that has one vector of weight 0, 4 of weight 2, 6 of weight 4, 4 of weight 6, and one of weight 8.)